# How to read a file into unsigned char array from std::ifstream?

Tags: c++, boost, std, boost-iostreams

So normaly I do stuff like:

```
    std::ifstream stream;
    int buff_length = 8192;
    boost::shared_array<char> buffer( new char[buff_length]);
    stream.open( path.string().c_str(), std::ios_base::binary);
    while (stream)
    {
            stream.read(buffer.get(), buff_length);
            //boost::asio::write(*socket, boost::asio::buffer(buffer.get(), stream.gcount()));
    }
    stream.close();
```

I wonder how to read into `unsigned char` buffer ( `boost::shared_array<unsigned char> buffer( new unsigned char[buff_length]);`)

Comment: One of the cases where `reinterpret_cast<>` is actually the correct approach.

Comment: Also, I'd prefer a shared_ptr<std::vector<uint8_t>> to shared_array

Answer (score 14):

In a simplest form:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> vec(
      std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cin)
    , std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()
    );
```

Replace `std::cin` with your actual stream.

The above is likely to do more than one memory allocation (for files larger than a very few bytes) because `std::istreambuf_iterator<>` is an input-iterator, not a random-access or a forward iterator, so the length of the file can't be measured by subtracting iterators like `end - begin` or calling `std::distance(begin, end)`. It can be reduced to one memory allocation if the vector is created first empty, then `std::vector<>::reserve()` is called to allocate memory for the file length and finally range insert is called `vec.insert(vec.end(), beg, end)` with `beg` and `end` being `std::istreambuf_iterator<>` as above to read the entire file.

If the file size is more then a few kilo-bytes it may be most efficient to map it into the process memory to avoid copying memory from the kernel to user-space.

The reason `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` is used is because the implementation uses `std::char_traits<>` which normally has specializations only for `char` and `wchar_t`. Regardless, the C and C++ standards require all `char` types to have the same binary layout with no padding bits, so conversions between `char`, `unsigned char` and `signed char` (which are all distinct types, unlike `signed int` and `int` being the same type) preserve bit patterns and thus are safe.

[[basic.fundamental/1]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.fundamental#1)

> Plain `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are three distinct types, collectively called *narrow character types*. A `char`, a `signed char`, and an `unsigned char` occupy the same amount of storage and have the same alignment requirements; that is, they have the same object representation... For narrow character types, all bits of the object representation participate in the value representation... For unsigned narrow character types, each possible bit pattern of the value representation represents a distinct number. These requirements do not hold for other types. In any particular implementation, a plain `char` object can take on either the same values as a `signed char` or an `unsigned char`; which one is implementation-defined. For each value `i` of type `unsigned char` in the range 0 to 255 inclusive, there exists a value `j` of type `char` such that the result of an integral conversion from `i` to `char` is `j`, and the result of an integral conversion from `j` to `unsigned char` is `i`.

Comment: The standards don't require that `char c = -1;  unsigned char u = c;` results in `c` and `u` having the same bit pattern. In theory signed chars could use 1's complement or sign-magnitude.

Comment: *Non-negative* values of signed char must have the same representation as the corresponding unsigned char. But in one's complement for example, `char c = -1;` has bit pattern 11111110  whereas `unsigned char u = c;` has bit pattern 11111111. This is mostly academic as I'm not aware of any C++ implementation ever that didn't use 2's complement

Comment: @M.M Added the quote for you.

Comment: They clearly don't have the same value representation ; the value `-1` does have a value representation in `signed char` but not in `unsigned char`

Comment: @M.M Added a longer quote for you. _Value representation_ is different (the sign bit). _Object representation_ is the same.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin that text (added in C++14) appears to require that *if plain char is signed* it must follow 2's complement. But firstly, there is no equivalent requirement in C as you claim, and secondly, it still permits  `signed char c = -1;` to use one's complement (i.e. get bit pattern 11111110) and have plain char be unsigned